# Different with Microsoft Azure AD Module PowerShell and Microsoft Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I try run command `Set-MsolDomainAuthentication` with Microsoft Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell. But i get exception, when try connect to my azure account(`connect-msolservice`). I type email and password, then i get:[image]

I try find solution in Google, Azure Support but everything what i find is useless.

On my system, I have an application which is called `Microsoft Azure PowerShell`[link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/). In this app, i can connect with my azure account, through command `Add-AzureAccount`. But this time, i don't find analogue to `Set-MsolDomainAuthentication`.

This command exists in Azure PowerShell? 
I can change Azure AD other way, like command `Set-MsolDomainAuthentication`? Maybe Azure Admin Panel? Or `GraphApi`?

Comment: Did you install the [MSOL Sign-in Assistant](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41950) when you installed the Azure AD PowerShell module?

Comment: @BenV Yes, Azure AD PoweShell Module installation required this apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with Powershell. This exception i getting when I try logging credential from account MicrosoftLive. Powershell required account in your domain.

So: 
Create a new user in a azure domain in role GlobalAdmin, change password this user, by logging in Office365, enter the PowerShell Credential this user.

Good luck.